# RestSharp: ExecuteAsync<T> never responds

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I am trying to make an async get request using `ExecuteAsync<T>`, but it never responds. The confusing thing to me is that `ExecuteAsync` works, as do both synchronous methods `Execute` and `Execute<T>`.

Here is my code:

```
var restClient = new RestClient("http://localhost:44268/api/");
var request = new RestRequest("jobs/{id}", Method.GET);
request.AddUrlSegment("id", "194");

// works
var req1 = restClient.Execute(request).Content;

// works
var req2 = restClient.Execute<Job>(request).Content;

// works
var req3 = restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, (restResponse) =>
{
    var test = restResponse.Content;
    Console.WriteLine(test);
});

var req4 = restClient.ExecuteAsync<Job>(request, (restResponse) =>
{
    // this code is never reached
    var test = restResponse.Content;
    Console.WriteLine(test);
});
```

It *is* successfully making the call to the API, but it just never calls back. Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: it's possible there's an exception being thrown before the callback is executed. can you go to Debug > Exceptions and tell it to break on all CLR exceptions?

Comment: I just tried that, and I got the same results, unfortunately. I still am not receiving the callback.

Comment: what platform is the client running on? which version of restsharp? can you try the 103.1-beta pre-release package on nuget?

Comment: The client is a .NET 4.0 console app. I _was_ using the 103.0.0 version from Nuget. I updated to the 103.1-beta pre-release like you said, and the issue was resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved by upgrading to the latest version of RestSharp.

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteAsync` is asynchronous.

That means the calls to it return immediately without waiting for a response.

Then your program continues as normal. If this is a console app and execution comes to the end of your `Main` method, the whole program will exit.

So, you have a race condition. Most of the time, your program will exit before the continuations ( the lambda callbacks ) have a chance to run.

Try putting a `Console.ReadLine();` call at the end of your `Main` method to prevent early exit.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I do have a `Console.ReadLine()` after this code, and if I put a breakpoint in the 3rd example that uses `ExecuteAsync`, it calls back just fine. However, the 4th example that uses `ExecuteAsync<Job>`, it never hits the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

```
public  Task<IRestResponse> ExecuteAsync<T>(RestRequest request, RestClient client)
{
  EventWaitHandle executedCallBack = new AutoResetEvent(false);
  TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();

IRestResponse res = new RestResponse();   
    try
    {
      var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<RestResponse>(request, response =>
        {
          res = response;
          tcs.TrySetResult(res);
          executedCallBack.Set();
        });


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      tcs.TrySetException(ex);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IRestResponse loginResponse = new RestResponse();
                    TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();

//Task task = new Task(() => {client.ExecuteAsync<RestResponse>(request, tcs.SetResult);});// Lambda and anonymous method  
Task task = new Task(() =>client.ExecuteAsync<RestResponse>(request, tcs.SetResult)); // Lambda and named method                    
task.Start();
loginResponse = await tcs.Task;
```